# E11000 duplicate key error collection: reklamaswin.ads index: username_1 dup key: { : null }

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why am I getting this error? E11000 duplicate key error collection: reklamaswin.ads index: username_1 dup key: { : null } when I want to make a new ad. I know that there is a duplicate somewhere, but I can't find where is the problem. Here are my schemas that I use in the project and the post request that goes to "/new". I'm creating a new Ad and storing it in the ads collection and then pushing it into the user.ads for the req.user

```js
router.post('/new', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
     if (err) {
        req.flash('error', err.message);
        return res.redirect('/new');
     }

     var ad = new Ad({
       banner: '/uploads/' + req.file.filename,
       url: req.user.url,
       paymentType: req.body.paymentType,
       transactionId: req.body.transactionId
     });

     ad.save(function(err, ad) {
       if (err) {
         req.flash('error', err.message);
         return res.redirect('/new');
       }

       User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
         if (err) {
           req.flash('error', err.message);
           return res.redirect('/new');
         }

         user.ads.push(ad);
         user.save(function(err, ad) {
           if (err) {
             req.flash('error', err.message);
             return res.redirect('/new');
           }
           req.flash('success', 'Successfully added new ad.');
           res.redirect('/');
         });
       });
     });
  });
});
```

This is the Ad schema.

```js
var AdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  banner: String,
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  url: String,
  paymentType: {
    type: String,
    default: 'free'
  },
  transactionId: String,
  sponsored: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

This is the User schema.

```js
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String,
  joined: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  siteRole: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  ads: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ad'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: reklamaswin.ads index: username_1 dup key: { : null }
```

- This error says that there is a `username` index on collection `reklamaswin.ads`
- The index seems to be unique hence all documents that have `username`: `null` creates a conflict in uniqueness.
- One way to solve this is to find out all such documents with `username` is not set and set it
- Also, you can drop the index optionally

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly without knowing what your collection indexes are but it appears there is an index for the Ads collection named `username_1`. Indexes with this name format are typically created by Mongoose when setting `index: true` on a field. In this case apparently there was a `username` field with `index: true` on the Ads schema at some point.

Also, the `null` message is indicating that an index entry exists where this field is `null` -- expected since the field no longer exists on the Ads collection. So any new records would also have a `null` value for this field and would therefore create a duplicate key error.

If this assumption is true then the fix would be to drop the `username_1` index on the Ads collection.

Comment: Hello, but I don't have a username_1index in my ads collection, you can see in the top.

Comment: @AmirŠaran The provided code only shows your current schema, not what the mongoDB actually has. This would include indexes and collections created by previous versions of or other code that was run against the same mongoDB instance. If you were to inspect the mongoDB instance directly then you would see these indexes.